# Moodle Integration Sample Sites or the way to do it

Tags: integration

Where can I find a successful Moodle Integration example or see a sample site? If not how to go about doing the integration? Thanks

Comment: It would help if you explained what level of integration you are looking for and what CMS etc. The only use case we have looked at was only going to require single sign on - which in the end did not happen - but that would have been a Drupal - Moodle issue, not a CiviCRM one

Comment: I am interested in CiviCRM integration with Moodle 2.9 the database is mySQL 
Are there any example sites/implementations that I can see 
Has it ever been done? 
Is it possible if not very likely so I can spend time on this or should I not bother? Thanks .. Z

Comment: Ziad, I think what Pete is getting at is that you haven't explained what type of integration you're looking to achieve. Are you wanting students' information kept as CiviCRM contacts, or creating events that are managed by CiviCRM, but you want to tie in docs kept in Moodle, etc. Without knowing how you want to integrate, I don't know that someone will be able to help direct you.

Comment: We are using Moodle LMS and would like to use CiviCRM for customer relations management which mean we want the CRM to pull students data from the LMS and use it seamlessly. I am not sure of much technical jargon and/or even if it is possible to make these work together at all. So any feedback will be helpful whether we should even look into the possibility because all I have read is CMS integration but no LMS. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No such integration exists today so there is no sample. To implement such integration, I would recommend building an extension for CiviCRM that could interface with Moodle's APIs:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Core_APIs

You could also consider the opposite, creating a Moodle plugin that would interface with the CiviCRM API:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API

Comment: any such thing done on this @ziad khan ?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on some CiviCRM-Moodle integration in 2017 with Monish Deb.  The main product of that work is [CiviMoodle](https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.civimoodle).

With CiviMoodle, users can be created in Moodle from CiviCRM. It also adds a field on the back end of Civi events with a drop-down of all Moodle courses. If you select one, someone registering in Civi will have their corresponding Moodle user registered for that course.

A second extension was written, to bring grades in Moodle into Civi custom fields.  However, this isn't really useful to others except perhaps as an example.

Comment: I think this is a sensible and useful approach to Moodle/CiviCRM integration. It makes sense to manage users in CiviCRM and then have SSO from Moodle to do all the learning functionality. This is how I first heard of CiviCRM when we were running many Moodle projects and needed something to do user registration and event booking.