# Integrating Moodle With CiviCRM

Tags: wordpress, integration

We currently have a WordPress site. We currently use CiviCRM 4.7.15. We are using Moodle underneath the WP. So, we have http://iafst.com/ as the main containing CiviCRM and http://iafst.com/iafstuniv/ running the Moodle.

We would like to bring the students registering via the Moodle under the umbrella of CiviCRM.

Is there anything anyone is aware of to look at for a Best Practices of doing this? We have CPanel access.

Thanks for all you folks do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear to me that this question is a duplicate of:

[Moodle Integration Sample Sites or the way to do it](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6940/moodle-integration-sample-sites-or-the-way-to-do-it/17383#17383)

and there is a good answer on that page.